# Android: Programmatically triggering phone checkin

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast

From within my Android application, I need to make the phone 'checkin' with Google for Market updates.  This can be done manually by the user by opening the dialer and typing '`*#*#CHECKIN#*#*`'.  My app needs the ability to do the same thing.

I'm positive this done using an Intent.  Some digging shows that the Alarm Manager has this pending intent waiting:

```
  RTC_WAKEUP #5: Alarm{44b1ee18 type 0 com.google.android.server.checkin}
    type=0 when=1277981220358 repeatInterval=40212000 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{44b256c0: PendingIntentRecord{44c26a80 com.google.android.server.checkin broadcastIntent}}
```

Now the question is, how do I get my app to broadcast this same type of Intent?  I tried this.sendBroadcast(myIntent) in the activity with no luck, so I'm rather stumped at the moment.

Any thoughts?

Comment: NOTE: I'm fully aware that using private APIs is a huge no-no.  This app is NOT going to be distributed on the Market.  This app is a one-click patch for rooted, custom-ROM users.  I'm not worried about this breaking in the future, since its a single-use, one-time app.  That said, does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collinodell,

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:*%23*%232432546%23*%23*")));
```

I got it today by hex encoding the #, and calling the dialer. Root66 gave me the tip

jcase

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on this functionality. This is an undocumented API, and it's undocumented for a reason.

This can (and likely will) change in future releases of the Android Market app. Since your application is relying on this functionality, this means your application will break.

Comment: I completely understand and usually agree with this.  However, this particular application is a single-use app designed to fix an issue some rooted users are experiencing with custom ROMs.  It's not intended for use by the masses or anything like that, which is why I (and those who would use the app) don't mind the possibility of it 'breaking' in the future.  Its just a quick fix I'm hoping to package into a simple APK for these rooted users.

Comment: Punching that code into the dialer is considered more work than asking users to find, download, install and run another app?

Comment: @adamp: It's one of many things the app needs to perform.  Would be nice if it could do all of them with a single click instead of sending the user to the dialer and then making them come back into the app.